# Python "Rock, Paper, Scissors" validation

Tags: python

I have been making a rock paper scissors game, and it works like a dream. However, when I try to add some validation in (shown with the `#`'s) my game doesn't work. I'm not sure why this is the case.

My code is following:

```
    from random import randint
    from sys import exit
    computer = randint(1,3)

    r = "r"
    p = "p"
    s = "s"
    print ("The computer has chosen. Your turn")
    player = input ("r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")

    #from here

    if (player != r or p or s): 
            player = input ("That wasn't r, p, or s. Please try again. r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")
            if (player != r or p or s) :
                    print ("Can you srsly not understand that " + player + " is not r, p, or s? I give up")
                    exit()


    #to here



    if (computer == 1):
            AI = ("rock")

    if (computer == 2):
            AI = ("paper")

    if (computer == 3):
            AI = ("scissors")

    if (player == r and computer == 1):
            print ("lol draw")
            exit()

    if (player == p and computer == 2):
            print ("lol draw")
            exit()

    if (player == s and computer == 3):
            print ("lol draw")
            exit()

    if (player == r and computer == 3):
            print ("You WIN!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == p and computer == 1):
            print ("You WIN!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == s and computer == 2):
            print ("You WIN!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == s and computer == 1):
            print ("You LOSE!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == r and computer == 2):
            print ("You LOSE!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)

    if (player == p and computer == 3):
            print ("You LOSE!!!!!! AI chose " + AI)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Now code 'rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock.'

Comment: WELL... it looks like my qu has been answered. TY

Comment: Remember to put a checkmark next to the correct question.

Comment: I think u mean answer

Comment: Doh! Yes. I mean answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `or` operator again.

```
player != r or p or s
```

Should be

```
player not in (r, p, s)
```

or similar.

**Explanation:**

`A or B` evaluates to `A`, if `A` is considered true (truey). If `A` is considered falsy (e.g. `False`, `0`, `0.0`, `[]`, `''`), `A or B` evaluates to `B`.

`player != r or p or s` is the same as `(player != r) or p or s`. Now `(player != r) or p or s` evaluates to `True` if `player != r` and to `p` otherwise. As both `True` and `p` are "truey", these two lines are equivalent:

```
if player != r or p or s:
if True:
```

Comment: Glad to help, and please read my explanation and try to digest it. And read the documentation of python's logical operator.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version of your code using a few more advanced python idioms:

```
from random import randint
from sys import exit
computer = randint(0,2)
choices = 'rps'

print ("The computer has chosen. Your turn")
player = raw_input("r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")

if (player not in choices): 
    player = raw_input("That wasn't r, p, or s. Please try again. r is Rock, p is Paper, and s is Scissors. Put your letter in HERE-----> ")
    if (player not in choices):
        print ("Can you srsly not understand that '%s' is not r, p, or s? I give up" % player)
        exit()

if (player == choices[computer]):
        print ("lol draw, AI also chose %s" % choices[computer])
        exit()

flip = choices.index(player) > computer
result = ("WIN", "LOSE")[(flip + choices.index(player) - computer) % 2] 
print ("You %s!!!!!! AI chose %s" % (result, choices[computer]))
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
if (player != r or p or s):
```

to this

```
if player != r and player != p and player != s:
```

Comment: To explain why, since I'm guessing you're newish:

What you have is equivalent to (not real Python code):

Comment: this answer is incorrect `x != True or x != False` will always yield `True`...should be `and` not `or`

Answer (score 1):

What you have is equivalent to (not real Python code):
`if player != r or if p or if s` which is not what you want: since `p` and `s` are already defined as true your if statement will trigger every time.

You want `if player != r and player != p and player != s` (i.e., none of the three things are true)

`if player not in [r, p, s]` would also work equivalently if you prefer--I think it's a little more Pythonic.

Comment: Not according to my repl.

`player = 'r'
p = 'p'
s = 's'
if (player != r or p or s): 
    print 'yes'
if (player != r):
    print 'no'`

gives yes.

Comment: OK, `player != r or p or s` is `True` iff `player != r`, and otherwise it is `p`. So basically it is always `True`.

Comment: No worries--I actually had a totally different error in my code anyway, which I've fixed.  Mind removing your downvote?  They make me sad.

Comment: I will as soon as I am off CD.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the syntax issue, however I feel that in following a similar structure as presented, the '“Rock, Paper, Scissors” validation' can be greatly cleaned up.

```
# read player input and return "r", "p" or "s"
def getPlayerChoice():
    # return value read from input, as per your code, with the fixes.

# read computer choice and return "r", "p" or "s"
def getComputerChoice():
    # return "r", "p", or "s" based on the random number

# get the "English" name of a value
def getName(rps):
    # given "r", "p", or "s", return the name like "rock", etc.

# now these two variables will have the value "r", "p" or "s"
# no numbers, no "rock", just some consistent values
player = getPlayerChoice()
computer = getComputerChoice()

# By using consistent values we are able to make the tie check very easy
# and make the win checks easy to read.

# chose same value - "r", "p" or "s"
if player == computer:
    print("Tie")

# all ways player could have won
elif (   (player == "r" and computer == "s")
      or (player == "p" and computer == "r")
      or (player == "s" and computer == "p")):
    print("You win! " + getName(player) + " beats " + getName(computer))

# otherwise the computer won
else:
    print("You lose! " + getName(computer) + " beats " + getName(player))
```

YMMV, and any bugs in the above structure are "freebies".

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to downvote because this isn't valid python.

Comment: @SethMMorton That's fine, it definitely is not. I did fix the grievous misuses of &&/||/; and the conditional expression. Silly rushed me.